# service worker cache fallback to network

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

> Service Worker

even though the service worker cache version changed, the .js and .css files in browser cache are not updating unless clearing them manually!!!

i am using cache fallback to network strategy

please assist a solution to do it programatically

service worker

```
//cache version 
var apbcw_cache = "APBCW - 1.9";

// files to cache
var filesToCache = [
    'pwa.html',
    'assets/mountains.png',
    'assets/camera.png',
    'css/pwa.css',
    'js/pwa.js',
    'js/network.js',
    'js/iDBconn.js',
    'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',
    'js/manifest.json',
    'assets/icons/android-icon-144x144.png',
    'assets/icons/apple-icon-144x144.png',
    'assets/icons/ms-icon-144x144.png'
];

//install Service Worker
self.addEventListener('install',function(event){
    console.log('Service Worker installed', event);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(apbcw_cache)
        .then(function(cache){
            console.log("caching files");
            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.error("Error adding files to cache",error);
        })
    )
    self.skipWaiting();
});

// activate Service Worker
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event){
    console.log('Service Worker activated',event);
    console.log('cache version: ',apbcw_cache);
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
        .then(function(keyList){
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key){
                if(key !== apbcw_cache){
                    console.log("deleting old cache:", key);
                    return caches.delete(key)
                }
            }));
        })
    ); 
    return self.clients.claim();
});

//fetch event 
self.addEventListener('fetch',function(event){
    console.log("Service Worker is fetching" + event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function(response){
            return response || fetch(event.request)
        })
    )
})
```

Comment: AFAICT it looks good.
Have you tried to name the cache without spaces? I honestly have never named a cache with spaces before so that is the first place I would look.
I would also check to see if the files being referenced at the new files and not previous versions on the server, even if it is localhost.
Also check the network and inspect the files as they are loaded to see if they are updated.

Comment: caches are getting deleted when we change a version but css and js file are not updating in browser cache files unless we clear them manually

Comment: This is my opinion on Cache-Control headers and service workers.
If you are going to cache an asset using service worker then the Cache-Control header is sort of moot. I know all the best practices out there preach using a Cache-Control header, but a service worker really supersedes it.
A new feature in the newest Chrome (not sure if it has shipped to general yet) is the service worker will ignore the browser cache. That may help you out.
I still use Cache-Control headers, but I set them for shorter times than I used to do.